# javascript parseInt to remove spaces from a string

Tags: javascript, parsing, numbers, parseint

I have an example of data that has spaces between the numbers, however I want to return the whole number without the spaces:

```
mynumber = parseInt("120 000", 10);
console.log(mynumber); // 120
```

i want it to return `120000`. Could somebody help me with this?
thanks

### update

the problem is I have declared my variable like this in the beginning of the code:

```
var mynumber = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
```

apparently this is causing a problem with your solutions provided.

Comment: Did you mean to type `parseInt('120 000', 10)`?

Comment: @MikeC yes i updated it, sorry.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can remove all of the spaces from a string with [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) before processing it.

```js
var input = '12 000';
// Replace all spaces with an empty string
var processed = input.replace(/ /g, '');
var output = parseInt(processed, 10);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: i updated my question, i currently have problem integrating your response.

Comment: @marcel Assigning `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` to it will not cause any problems. You're just re-assigning `mynumber` to a different value, presumably. Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem and I'd be more than happy to help you solve it. If you need something to help you quickly hash it out, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) is great for that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove all whitespaces inside string by a replace function.
2. using the `+` operator convert the string to number.

```js
var mynumber = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER;
mynumber = "120 000";
mynumber = mynumber.replace(" ", ""); 
console.log(+mynumber );
```

Comment: i updated my question, i can't succeed applying your solution

Comment: The `Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER` constant represents the minimum safe integer in JavaScript. If your myNumber is assigned that value, then why are you converting it again to number ? In case, you are overriding the value from number to a string, then also it should work. I updated the answer as per your comment.

Comment: the problem is that not all of the instances of `mynumber` has space, so this solution breaks when there is not. what should i do then?

Comment: which string value is it failing? this solution should work for any numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all white space with replace function

```
var mynumber = "120 000";
console.log(mynumber.replace(/ /g,''));
```

OutPut is 120000

Answer (score 0):

Just like playing with javascript  :-)

```
var number= '120 00'; 
var s= '';
number = parseInt(number.split(' ').join(s), 10);
alert(number);
```